# R plotly: Add text in polar scatter plot

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot

Let's say I have a simple scatter plot using R `plotly`.
And I want to put text at each points of scatter plot as shown.

**Simple R polar chart**:

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  r = c(0,1,2,2),
  theta = c(0,45,90,120),
  size = c(10, 20, 30, 40),
  sizes = c(100, 300),
  mode = 'markers'
)
p
```

**Output Chart**:

[image]

In the same way using `plot_ly` with `scatterpolar`, How can I put text at the center of each bubble with some value let's say value of `size` column.?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding answer, for future reference in SO community.
I found the solution using `add_trace`

**R code**:

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  r = c(0,1,2,2),
  theta = c(0,45,90,120),
  size = c(10, 20, 30, 40),
  sizes = c(100, 300),
  mode = 'markers'
) %>%
  add_trace(
    r = c(0,1,2,2), 
    theta = c(0,45,90,120),
    mode = "text",
    text = c(10, 20, 30, 40),
    textfont = list(color = '#000000', size = 12)
  ) 
p
```

**Chart**:

[image]